# Club Two Queries in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have written a separate query for finding the roots and also for finding the shortest path. I want to club the two queries to find the network and connections between root nodes and shortest path network. I have written a query as

```
match (u:Port1)<-[r]-(root)
where not((root)<--())
with  distinct(root.id) as Node
match p = ( (Node)-[]->(n)-[:LinkTo*1..]->(m) )
where id(Node)< id(n) < id(m)
return p, (length(p)) order by length(p) desc limit 10
```

Is my query correct? I get an error as

> Neo.DatabaseError.Statement.ExecutionFailed: Expected to find a node at Node but found 2 instead

Can anyone please correct my CQL query?

Comment: use `with  distinct(root) as Node`

Comment: I have already put that statement into the code. Should I put it again? And where should I put it?

Comment: You don't have that in your query. You have `with  distinct(root.id) as Node`. Then you try to use `Node` to match on the next line. But this fails because `Node` is an integer id, not a node. So replace that line with: `with distinct(root) as Node` so the variable is bound to a node instead of an integer.

Comment: I think the code has run into time and space complexity. It isn't returning any results. I tried it in GrapheneDB. No results returned! Any modifications to be further done?

Comment: Can you clarify? Is it not returning at all, just running forever? Or is it returning, but with no results? If it's returning but with no results, then something is wrong with the query. You might check to make sure your spelling and cases are correct for labels and relationships, and that such a pattern you're looking for actually exists in the query.

Comment: It's running forever. It keeps rotating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Expected to find a node at Node but found 2 instead` says that your identifier `Node` was supposed to be a node but was not, and this is because you are setting it to the node id `root.id`.
Use the `root` node itself-

`match (u:Port1)<-[r]-(root)
where not((root)<--())
with  distinct(root) as Node
match p = ( (Node)-[]->(n)-[:LinkTo*1..]->(m) )
where id(Node)< id(n) < id(m)
return p, (length(p)) order by length(p) desc limit 10`